# How to wait for a successful async action before changing url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await

so I'm using a popup to log my users in with firebase:

```
const loginToApp = (provider) => {
    firebaseApp
        .auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(async (result) => {
            if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                // problem is this line
                await setNewUserInformation(result.user.uid)
            }
            const { user } = result
            setUser(user)
            // and this line
            window.location.href = 'newRoute'
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('ERROR:', error)
        })
}
```

so if I remove `window.location.href = 'visited'` this all works fine and it sets in firebase. I'm probably doing something stupid but I cant figure out how to wait for this function to fire `setNewUserInformation` and to complete before I move to the new page?

function code:

```
export const setNewUserInformation = (userId) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_NEW_USER_INFORMATION',
        userId,
    }
}
```

this then has a redux observable epic listening to it:

```
return action$.pipe(
    ofType('SET_NEW_USER_INFORMATION'),
    mergeMap((action) => {
        return from(
            firebaseApp.database().ref(firebaseRef).update(userInformation),
        ).pipe(
            mergeMap(() => {
                return [updatedUserInformationSuccess()]
            }),
            catchError((error) => of(updatedUserInformationFailure(error))),
        )
    }),
)
```

Comment: how does the function looks like?

Comment: @Ifaruki I'll add code. but it's just an action creator that then has a redux observable listening to it

Comment: @Ifaruki added code

Comment: well fact is that you are using `await` on a function with is NOT returning an promise.

Comment: I thought `from` returns a promise in redux-observable

Comment: well you use `await` on `setNewUserInformation` witch is returning an object. await will just await only this function

Comment: ah yeh, you're right. hmm, I wonder how I can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setNewUserInformation()` is an action creator, which is sync. You do not need to wait for it as it does not return anything useful to you logic. What you need to do, is move `window.location.href = 'newRoute'` to separate logic, and make it depend on state returned from action creators `updatedUserInformationSuccess()` and updatedUserInformationFailure(error). If your component is functional, put this logic in a `useEffect`. If it is a class component, use `ComponentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

Comment: ah this helped me. moved to useEffect, then waiting for redux to update before I switch page.cheers bro! up mark the question if you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below

```
const loginToApp = (provider) => {
firebaseApp
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(async (result) => {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                // problem is this line
                setNewUserInformation(result.user.uid)
            }
           const { user } = result
           resolve(user)
        }).then((user)=>{
          setUser(user)
          // and this line
          window.location.href = 'newRoute'
        })
       
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR:', error)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because on `then` You can returned a Promise and resolve later. We could re-write the code above like this below:

```
const loginToApp = (provider) => {
    firebaseApp
        .auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                // return for next resolve function
                return setNewUserInformation(result.user.uid).then(() => result); 

            }
            return result;
        })
        .then((result) => {
            // after all above promises resolve
            const { user } = result
            setUser(user)
            // and this line
            window.location.href = 'newRoute'
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('ERROR:', error)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React?
If yes, then you can simply use didUpdate Cycle to route to new url after successful action dispatched. Move your "window.location.href = 'newRoute'" under the ComponentDidUpdate with props check.

Comment: I'm using a functional component. I know I can still do this with them but the problem is with my redux observable

Comment: I think, anyway